# Set schema name in SqlUserDefinedTypeAttribute

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, sqlclr, user-defined-types

When creating a UserDefinedType in C# code for the sake of SQLCLR integration, it is required that you prefix a class or struct with a SqlUserDefinedType, such as here:

```
[SqlUserDefinedType(
    Name = "g.Options",
    // ...
)]
public struct Options : INullable {
    // ...
}
```

Notice that in the "Name" parameter, I attempt to set a schema in addition to the object name.  But, when I generate the script in the publish stage of a Visual Studio Database Project, I get:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[g.Options]
```

There is no "schema" parameter for SqlUserDefinedType.

I do believe I can write the T-SQL script to make the type from the assembly specifically, but I would like to avoid that, as I plan on putting most of my types in different schemas and wouldn't be happy to have to register via explicit TSQL on each one.

---

**EDIT:**

As Solomon Rutzky points out, you can set the Default Schema in the project properties.  It is certainly no substitute for something akin to a 'schema' parameter in SqlUserDefinedType, particularly if you want to work with multiple schemas, but it certainly gets the job done for many people's needs.

A post-deployment script will technically get the job done, but unfortunately, the comparison engine doesn't know about the post-deployment logic and so will perpetually register the schema difference as something that needs to be changed.  So all your affected objects will be dropped and re-created on every publish regardless of whether you changed them or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Schema name is specified in a singular location per each project, not per object.

You can set it in Visual Studio via:

"Project" (menu) -> "{project_name} Properties..." (menu option) -> "Project Settings" (tab)

On the right side, in the "General" section, there is a text field for "Default schema:"

OR:

you can manually edit your **{project_name}.sqlproj** file, and in one of the top `<PropertyGroup>` elements (one that does not have a "Condition" attribute; the first such element is typically used), you can create (or update if it already exists) the following element:

```xml
<DefaultSchema>dbo</DefaultSchema>
```

HOWEVER, if you are wanting to set one object (such as a UDT) to a different Schema name than the rest of the objects are using, that would have to be done manually in a Post Release SQL script. You can add a SQL script to your project, then in the Solution Explorer on the right side, select the SQL script, go to its Properties, and for "BuildAction", select "**PostDeploy**". In that post-deploy script, issue an [ALTER SCHEMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql) statement:

```sql
ALTER SCHEMA [g] TRANSFER TYPE::dbo.Options;
```

Comment: I don't think I would do the post deploy route because it would mess with schema compare.  It would always work, but it would also always tell me that the clr objects will need updating by virtue of the name difference.  I might consider a different project with a different assembly owner.  But I don't want to create a different project per schema.  But at least it would allow me to create one separate schema for the clr objects.

Comment: I gave this a try, but not much luck.  I gave my experience as an edit in the question.  Thanks for the option though.

Comment: I may have copied/pasted the wrong element. I will check when I get home.

Comment: @pwilcox Yeah, I had grabbed the wrong element. I have updated with the correct info. Please try again. Also, have you tried the post release script option, or are you just assuming that it will get flagged as different? If you haven't tested it, I can see a case where it might work since it needs to find the objects based on their link to the assembly, not their names. Hence it _might_ ignore the schema part for UDTs.

Comment: I'm presently operating via the default schema setting.  Thank  you.  I'll test with post deploy sometime in the near future and add the results to the edit section of my question or to my comments.

Comment: @pwilcox Glad that worked out, at least for the moment. Yes, please do share the results of that testing. I will keep my finders cross ;-). Also, I get the frustration with the deployment options. This is why I gave up on SSDT many years ago and haven't looked back. I do all SQLCLR deployments manually. I just use Visual Studio for creating and compiling, and signing. Once it's a DLL, I take it from there. SSDT doesn't allow for setting parameter default values, no way to set `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` for UDFs, can't set `ORDER BY` on TVFs, no support for module signing, etc, etc.

Comment: Sorry Solomon, no such luck.  I added my experience to the question above.  But I can certainly think of worse things than having all of my CLR objects in a schema called "clr".  I just hope that default schema setting isn't needed elsewhere.  I'll also consider your SSDT limitations seriously in the future.  On the fence about it right now.